# Unity Code Snippets not auto-completing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, .net-core-sdk

I've come across a bug in Visual Studio Code involving the Unity Code Snippets extension and its auto-complete function.

After installing Visual Studio Code, in some cases, when you open the program you will get a notification that states "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path."

This will cause a bug in the Unity Code Snippets extension causing it to not auto-complete the code once inputted into the IDE.

Comment: Seems like the error message gives the answer to your question in fact. Not sure if this question has much merit then...

Comment: I assumed that the error message meant that specifically debugging would not be enabled. The auto-correct feature would be something completely different would it not?

Comment: code completion is usually based on internal compilation, but that expects some kind of compiler to be availibe behind the scenes, for .NET you need an SDK then

Comment: Great explanation! Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue:

1.) Click on the .NET Core SDK link that pops up in Visual Studio Code or simply google .NET Core SDK.

2.) Before installing .NET Core SDK, close Visual Studio Code.

3.) Re-install .NET Core SDK.

4.) Re-open Visual Studio Code and the auto-complete feature should work now!